# Graber bike rack installation on Honda Accord

Tags: mountain-bike

I have Graber 2 bike rack. 
While installing I noted top narrow side of Graber arm rest on top of the trunk and bottom wide arm rest on rear bumper.

How safe it is to carry bikes like this ?
If Bumper strong enough to hold 2 bike weight ?
Note that car is 17 years old.

Thank you,
V

Comment: This is so specific that I think there's a good chance nobody will know. But good luck! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used the Grabber 2 bike rack, but **it will be safe to use it to carry 2 bikes on your (1998-2002) Honda Accord**.

Generally, car bumpers are made up of **2 parts**: a metal bumper, and a bumper cover.

The **metal bumper** is the part that will take the impact if someone hits you from behind. The metal bumper for a 1998-2002 Accord is shown below.

[image: metal bumper]

On top of the metal bumper, there is a plastic **bumper cover**. Its only purpose is to make the car look nice. Your Grabber 2 rack will probably be resting on the bumper cover when you install it.

I highlighted the points where your rack will probably rest on the black 1998-2002 Accord bumper cover, shown below.
[image: bumper cover]

Below is a picture of a 1998-2002 Accord, with the same points highlighted.
[image: Accord]

You *might* notice the plastic bumper cover flex a little when you load the bikes, but this is nothing to worry about. The plastic they use for bumper covers is meant to take small impacts without cracking, so having the weight of 2 bikes resting on it will do no harm.

Comment: So much helpful answer. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

When properly installed these type of trunk mounted racks do not actually rest on the bumper.

The lower arm should be positioned slightly above the bumper and bottom edge of the vertical part of the trunk lid. The weight of the rack and bikes is actually supported by the top straps.

See the pictures at the Graber web site (not sure if it's exactly the same product, but it shows proper installation.)

https://www.graberproducts.com/product/guardian-elite-2